# How can I create a view that displays the most popular nodes based on an outgoing link?

Tags: 7, views, theming, blocks

The link is a text field that's value is pulled directly in **node.tpl**:

```
<a class="list-parent-link" href="<?php echo $node->field_download_link['und'][0]['value']; ?>">
```

I'd like to be able to track how popular each node's link is, and display the 5 most popular nodes in a views block. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/drupal-7-click-tracking-traffic-per-node

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done in a number of ways... some options:

1) add a JS onclick="" to the link which goes to a function that causes an ajax call to the server. The server would then take in node information and using something like the [Flag Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag):

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other
>   type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking
>   important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views
>   integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep
>   tabs on important content.

to trigger a counter which can then be easily used in Views.

2) adjust the link direction to an internal proxy page:

```
<a href="/mymodule/proxy?url=<?php echo $node->field_download_link['und'][0]['value']; ?>">
```

The proxy page would have a callback function that again uses Flag or similar to track the click and then redirect the page to the provided url.

Option 2 is probably the better of the two, but it depends on the set up, and whether or not you want a redirect, etc.

I can give more specific guidance if you decide to go with one of these.

Comment: I've been meaning to take you up on this. This is a side project and I've been jumping around on different issues that need solving. Which of these two would scale better? I don't mind redirecting.

Comment: if you're comfortable with a redirect (left as a blank white page, the end user may not even realise a redirect was made) then the second option is much simpler, and easier to manage long term

Comment: It definitely sounds easier to manage. Where do I start?

Comment: 1) create a custom module 2) create a page callback using hook_menu() 3) modify your links to include the redirect, including current node information (href="/custom_external_link_analytics?node=<?php echo $node->nid; ?>"  for example) 4) create the page callback and use the flag API to flag that particular node (now that you have been provided node information) - with the VOTE API, you can use flag to count the times a node is flagged.   5) use views with a relationship to the flag to show the content however you want - work one step at a time and a simple search should yield the details